# Apache Camel webservice routing using only soapheaders

Tags: cxf, apache-camel

We are working on project that needs to route soapmessages from one endpoint to 3, 4, 5 endpoint - a bit like a proxy, but the routing happends based on a "routingkey" in the soap header.

We have no problem in using the proxy example from the examples - so a "clean" proxy using DataFormat=MESSAGE works like a charm. The are a few pitfalls - the body message (payload) is encrypted and potential large >50mb - so streaming is important and the payload should not be parsed.

The CXF_MESSAGE looks the way to go, but we are not sure how to work with it or the DefaultMessage from exchange.getIn() ?

Maybe someone can give a hint ?

Best regards

Aage Nielsen

Comment: Would the [content based router](https://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html) work for you? Using the SOAP headers to determine the destination?

Comment: we have tried it from("cxf:bean:prxyws?dataFormat=MESSAGE").choice().when(header("no").isEqualTo("22")).to("ws1"); but it looks like the soapheaders are not available when the format is MESSAGE.

Comment: Using PAYLOAD data format didn't work neither?

Comment: How did you do in PAYLOAD data formate? You should be able get the soap header there.

Comment: How do you know that SOAP header are not available? are you sure about that???